# .bat How to replace text and preserve blank lines

Tags: batch-file, findstr

The code below does preserve space before each line in the example.yaml.  However, it removes all blank lines AND most importantly it doesn't even replace the text.

Does anyone know how to edit this code so that it will:

1. Preserve blank lines
2. Replace "filters:" with "filters: !yaml_filters!"

```
@echo off
echo how many filters
set /p yaml_filters=

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('"FINDSTR /B filters: example.yaml"') do set edit_line=%%i
SETLOCAL=ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
        rename example.yaml example.tmp
        for /f "delims=" %%a in (example.tmp) do (
            set foo=%%a
            if "!foo!"=="%edit_line%" (set foo=filters: !yaml_filters!)
            echo !foo! >> example.yaml)                                       
    del example.tmp
```

Comment: Just "replacing `filters:` with `filters: 34`" will change `filters: 12` to `filters: 3412`. Probably not what you want. By the way: if you filter for lines containing `filters:` before even processing them, there *are*  no empty lines.

Answer (score 2):

As others already noted, batch isn't a good tool for this task (not saying it's impossible but there are many caveats and quirks.

If you're willing to accept a third-party tool, I recommend jrepl.bat which makes your script just three lines (without having to worry about special chars, empty lines or leading (or trailing) spaces or tabs):

```
@echo off
set /p "yaml_filters=how many filters: "
call jrepl.bat "filters: \d*" "filters: %yaml_filters%" /f example.yaml /o -
```

If there is no other code afterward, you can even scratch the `call` command.

[Downloadlink jrepl.bat](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044). The author [dbenham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012053/dbenham) is a highly respected and trusted member on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Editing `yaml` files with batch files is not really the greatest idea, but that is what you request so I will give you a solution. Some notes:

1. The file cannot contain `!` as it will skip the characters due to `delayedexpansion`
2. The line you search for must match exactly, it cannot be partial line as we do not match for partial strings (substrings) So make sure you understand that if you want to match parts of the string, you need to modify the script to do so.

```
@echo off
set "myfile=example.yaml"
set "search=line to match"
set /p "replace=How many filters: "
for /f "tokens=1*delims=[]" %%a in ('type "%myfile%" ^| find /v /n "" ^& break ^> "%myfile%"') do (
       set "line=%%b"
       setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
       if "!line!"=="%search%" set "line=filters: !replace!"
       (echo(!line!)>>"%myfile%"
       endlocal
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not terribly far off:

```bat
@Echo Off & Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & CD "%~dp0"
rem // Qualify Parameters
If "%~3"=="" (Echo/^<Input File.ext^> ^<Search String^> ^<Insertion String^> & Exit /B 1)
rem // declare source file %1
  Set "Input=%~1"
  If not Exist "%Input%" Exit /B 1
rem // ensure no conflicting output file
  If Exist "tmp!Input!" Del /Q "tmp!Input!"
rem // iterate over source and output lines modified according to search pattern %2 and injected string %3
  For /F "Tokens=* Delims=" %%A in (!Input!) Do (
    Set "Line=%%A"
    ((Echo/!Line! | Findstr /B /I /L "%~2" >Nul 2> Nul) && Set "Line=%~2 %~3")
    Echo/!Line!
  )>>"tmp!input!"
rem // cleanup
  Del /Q "!input!"
  Set "RenFile=REN tmp!input! !input!"
  %RenFile%
  Endlocal & Exit /B 0
```

**Note:** The script is to be called with parameters indicated - I don't make a habit of posting 'exact' solutions as I find it better to provide a versatile answer that can easily be used by others with similar questions / problems